# No speedups with ProcessPoolExecutor() or even with numba

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numba

I am working on segmentation problem. For any image, there is a segemnted image which is label for that image. The segmented pixels contains information about different classes and the number of instances. Here is the code for it:

```
# Create an empty dataframe
data_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate over data.
for idx in range(40000):
    # Get the image name and corresponding label
    img_name = train_images[idx]
    label_name = train_labels[idx]
    label = imread(labels_dir / train_labels[idx])  #skimage.io.imread
    pixel_classes = find_unique(label)
    classes, instance_count = find_and_count(pixel_classes)
    data_dict = dict(zip(classes, instance_count))
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient='index').transpose()
    df.rename(columns=labelmap, inplace=True)
    df['img'] = img_name
    df['label'] = label_name

    # Concate to the final dataframe
    data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df], copy=False)
```

I tried `ProcessPoolExecutor()` to run things in parallel but it turned to be almost 5x slower than this single thread. I then tried to optimized some parts, dealing with `numpy` arrays, using `numba` but the performance is still almost the same. Can anyone please help me to speedup this loop?

Comment: Constructing and concatenating 40,000 single-row `DataFrame`s in a for loop will be slow no matter how you do it. I believe the biggest performance boost available to you is to rewrite this snippet to leverage parallelized `pandas/numpy` internals, rather than fight against it.

Comment: I can do a variation. Like I can store the intermediate dataframes in a list and concatenate in the end once the for loop is over but even that didn;t help

Comment: @jezrael your thoughts?